# Google Apps Script: How to invoke a function tied to a handler without user interaction?

Tags: javascript, android, google-apps-script

Hello I am completely new to programming and am wondering if someone can help me with this. I am creating an app using Google Apps. Is there a way to invoke a handler's function without a user having to interact with a trigger?

Example. I have an app that requires a date inputs. Once the dates are entered the user presses a button, which invokes the handler, to proceed to the next step by calling on a function. 
If I am loading a record from the database that already has a date saved, I would like the button to be hidden and the app to automaticaly proceed to the next step (function).

I know how to call another function within a function, but I do not know how to pass all the callback elements if the handler is not invoked, so that they can be called on in a manner such as:

e.parameter.widget1

e.parameter.widget2

e.parameter.......

I figure if I can cause the handler to automatically fire without the user having to press the button this would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do that in your doGet. In there you detect that condition, hide elements and call the handler function.
Now instead of faking the parameters of that handler, have another function that both your handler and your doGet call.

Comment: Thanks for your input Zig. In the function my handler calls, I refer to passed parameters as an example e.parameter.widget1, e.parameter.widget2... If both the handler and doGet calls the same function can I still call out widgets as such? 
My thinking is if I call a function in doGet without a handler I have to list all the passed elements individually but with a handler them seem to be all bundled in one element. So with a handler the called function appears as myFunction(e), instead of myFunction(element1, element2,..). But of course I am totaly new to this. Can you provide a quick example?

Comment: something like this: (button handler) onSave(e) { doSave(e.parameter.widget1, e.parameter.widget2); ... return ui;} this way doSave does not depend on 'e' and you can call it from anywhere you want, like your doGet. Your doSave is just function doSave(widget1, widget2). those widget1 etc are just strings.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I got this right. My doGet would call on doSave. My handler would call on onSave which in turn calls on doSave.

Comment: yes, both use the same function to do the work. I assume that there is a 2nd page that you are showing after that 1st step, so if you are modifying the interface, doSave would also need to do that. you could then have doSave itself modify the GUI and return the new gui. then from onSave you simply return doSave(...). Same goes for your doGet, on that special condition it returns the same return as doSave